# Reading and saving tif images with python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uinnoGNcgQ0tBRXC1PdovpzqI8tRsU2D/view?usp=sharing) tiff image with python. I have tried PIL to and save this image. The process goes smoothly, but  the output image seems to be plain dark. Here is the code I used.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('file.tif')
imarray = np.array(im)

data = Image.fromarray(imarray)
    
data.save('x.tif')
```

Please let me know if I have done anything wrong, or if there is any other working way to read and save tif images. I mainly need it as NumPy array for processing purposes.

Comment: You linked a PNG image, not a TIFF image...

Comment: The link image is a PNG. If you want to read a TIFF image, I suggest you use rasterio or gdal.

Comment: The website automatically converted it. Now I have updated the link.

Comment: According to ImageMagick, your TIFF is `TIFF 1024x1024 1024x1024+0+0 12-bit Grayscale Gray 1574650B` – I think PIL might have trouble reading 12-bit grayscale images (and even more so writing them back as-is). As @PabloSilió says, maybe try with `rasterio`.

Comment: can anyone help me with the code?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is simply that the image is dark. If you open it with PIL, and convert to a Numpy array, you can see the maximum brightness is 2455, which on a 16-bit image with possible range 0..65535, means it is only 2455/65535, or 3.7% bright.

```
from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('5 atm_gain 80_C001H001S0001000025.tif')

# Make into Numpy array
na = np.array(im)

print(na.max())       # prints 2455
```

So, you need to normalise your image or scale up the brightnesses. A VERY CRUDE method is to multiply by 50, for example:

```
Image.fromarray(na*50).show()
```

[image]

But really, you should use a proper normalisation, like `PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast()` or OpenCV `normalize()`.