# Save a Tiff Image

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I have a tiff image that I subdvise in many arrays and I rebuilt it in another image. I woud like to save save in TIFF image to keep the exact resolution but I don't understand why PIL or some librairy like this doesn't work. This is my code:

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import imageio
import PIL
from PIL import Image

# read the image stack
img=io.imread(r'C:\Users\pheni\Downloads\PICTURE.tiff')
# show the image
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
numpydata=np.array(img)
plt.imshow(numpydata)


x0=767
y0=228
pitch1=61
pitch2=61
N=numpydata[int(y0-pitch2/2):int(y0+pitch2/2),int(x0-pitch1/2):int(x0+pitch1/2)]
plt.imshow(N)

Tableau=np.zeros((66,66,pitch1,pitch2))

Image4=np.zeros([66,66]);

for i in range(0,56):
    for j in range(0,56):
            Tableau[i,j,:,:]=numpydata[int(y0+i*pitch2-pitch2/2):int(y0+i*pitch2+pitch2/2), int(x0+j*pitch1-pitch1/2):int(x0+j*pitch1+pitch1/2)]    
            Image4[i,j]=np.sum(Tableau[i,j,:,:]);

plt.imshow(Image4)
```

I tried with PIL but it look likes it's a problem of dimension However I can visualize my picture on plot but I cannot save it in TIFF (it's the only format that I can use for my job).

Thanks

I tried PIL and to reshape the array.

Answer (score 0):

To save an array `N` as a `.tiff` image:

```python
from PIL import image
dataout=Image.fromarray(N)

dataout.save('x.tiff')
```

Note that N has to be either a 2 dimensional array (like 600x400), to get a greyscale image or a 3 dimensional array with (dim<sub>x</sub>, dim<sub>y</sub>, n<sub>channel</sub>) to get a multi-channel image

(as can be seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967433/reading-and-saving-tif-images-with-python))

It is unclear what your are trying to do with your indices (`x0=767 y0=228 pitch1=61 pitch2=61`) or what is the size of your original image, so hard to say if reshaping is needed. Try to re-write your code using reference to the size of the original image, it would make it easier to help you.

In any case, the value of `y0+i*pitch2-pitch2/2)` with `i in range(0,56)` would vary from 197.5 to 12477.5  (and 604.0 to 19186.0 for x). Which might be larger than your original image.